# Circle and circumcircle angle-chasing

Tags: geometry, circles

The points $Q,R$ lie on the circle $\gamma$, and $P$ is a point such that $PQ, P R$ are tangents to $\gamma$. A is a point on the extension of $PQ$, and $\gamma'$ is the circumcircle of triangle $PAR$. The circle $\gamma'$ cuts $\gamma$ again at $B$, and $AR$ cuts $\gamma$ at the point $C$. Prove that $\angle PAR = \angle ABC$.

This question has a complex and interesting figure. It took me quite some time to understand the figure, I tried some constructions but couldn't come up with any leads. (BMO $1994$)

[image: geogebra figure]

Comment: Please draw a figure.

Comment: added a link to the figure

Answer (score 1):

Via angle chase, $\angle PAR = \angle ABC$. $\;\;:)$

---

Jokes aside, it is really just angle chasing: $$\angle ABP = \angle PRA=\angle RBC  \implies \angle ABC=\angle PBR=\angle PAR$$